# system sleep takes a long time

Tags: power-management

I just upgraded to `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`, from Debian 10. After the upgrade it is taking a long time to put the system to sleep.

E.g. the command `systemctl suspend`, locks the session quickly but takes 30 seconds to put the system to sleep. Is there a configuration that I don't know of (30s is the sort of delay that looks intentional). I get the same result when clicking the sleep widget.

## Edits to address some comments / answers

### output of `cat /etc/systemd/sleep.conf`

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; ...«ref to GPL»...
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See systemd-sleep.conf(5) for details

[Sleep]
#AllowSuspend=yes
#AllowHibernation=yes
#AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
#AllowHybridSleep=yes
#SuspendMode=
#SuspendState=mem standby freeze
#HibernateMode=platform shutdown
#HibernateState=disk
#HybridSleepMode=suspend platform shutdown
#HybridSleepState=disk
#HibernateDelaySec=180min
```

`systemctl hibernate` takes longer about 40s. It will not wake on key-press, and dose a normal boot via grub, but then goes in to waking from hibernate. Therefore the original command is a suspend to RAM, not hibernate to persistent memory (e.g. disk).

Answer (score 0):

Check [systemd-sleep.conf](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-systemd-sleep/) whether it's configured for `suspend`, `hibernate` or `hybrid-sleep`.

The latter two will write the full system state to swap, which will take a while, but you are safe from data loss during suspend.

Comment: I have updated question. I am 100% sure that it is doing suspend to RAM, but with a delay.